# console error when running npm start command in new react project

Tags: reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I would like you to help me repair an error that I have, is that every time I create a new project in react with the command `npx create-react-app app-name` and followed by a cd to the directory and an `npm start`, I says everything is correct:
Compiled successfully!

```
You can now view cacas in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://172.27.248.214:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciihG.png)

Followed by this I go to the browser, and I give f12 to start the inspector, and I run into the following errors:

**First error**

```
Error handling response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at chrome-extension://bmjmipppabdlpjccanalncobmbacckjn/js/content/content.js:60:21
```

**According to the error is in this line**

```
data = JSON.parse(data.cs_template);
```

**Full code shown**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++) {
        if (location.href.search(blacklist[i]) > 0)
            return;
    }

    cStyle = document.createElement('style');
    cStyle.id = 'cs_cursor_css_no_hd';
    document.head.appendChild(cStyle);

    if (!document.getElementById('elem_ext')) {
        elem_ext = document.createElement('div');
        elem_ext.id = 'elem_ext';
        elem_ext.style.display = 'none';
        document.documentElement.appendChild(elem_ext);
    }

    chrome.storage.local.get('storage_data', function (data) {
        if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('storage_data'))
            localStorage.removeItem('storage_data');
        localStorage.setItem('storage_data', data.storage_data);
        document.documentElement.dataset.csCursorMode = hd_mode;
        insert_cs_script();
    })


    chrome.storage.local.get('cs_template', function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data.cs_template);
        js = document.createElement('script');
        js.id = 'cs_cursor_template';
        js.innerHTML = data.template;
        document.head.appendChild(js);
    });



})
```

**Image showing what I already wrote above**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpUnU.png)

**Second error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:97
```

**The error sends me to this part of code**

```
var storage_data = (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('storage_data')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storage_data')) : {};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbyFA.png)

**Third error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showCsCursorNonHD is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:35
```

**The third error shows me this**

```
 cs_hd_mode = false;               showCsCursorNonHD();               hideCsCursor();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzhp6.png)

**It is a new project, without any change**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfLVm.png)

**Directories**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjoy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaahB.png)

**I have been using WSL2 for more than a year and about a month ago these errors began to appear when creating a new project in react**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to call `JSON.parse(...)` on something that is already a JS object. your `data` in the callback to `chrome.storage.local.get('cs_template',...)` is already a JS object. I am not sure what the structure of your data is, but data should be the actual `cs_template` object that can be accessed like `data.cs_template` in the callback function.

Comment: Well, I would like to tell you that it is a new project, that is, do not change anything, do not modify any data, or any line of code in the new project, as you can see in the images it is completely from 0, that is why I do not understand the errors

Comment: I discovered something interesting, if I enter with edge these errors are not shown